# How to get these tables stacked on top of each other?

Tags: html, css

How do I get these tables to slide under each other without the extra space?

[image]

```
<table border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>And another</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Some stuff in the table. </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Some stuff in the table. </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Some stuff in the table. </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>And another</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Some stuff in the table. </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Some stuff in the table. </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>And another</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Some stuff in the table. </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Some stuff in the table. </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Some stuff in the table. </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>And another</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Some stuff in the table. </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Some stuff in the table. </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Some stuff in the table. </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
/* ---------------[ Tables ]--------------- */

table {
    float: left;
    width: 285px;
    }

tr, td, th {
    margin:auto; 
    }

td, th {
    padding:5px;
    vertical-align:top;
    }

th {
    font-weight:bold;
    background:#ddd;
    }

td {
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Be sure to add that you want these tables in two columns. It wasn't specified in your question, although given the picture I believe understand what you're trying to accomplish. Currently you're getting a number of answers from people who I think misinterpreted the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try adding `clear: left` to your tables:

```
table {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 285px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/AsUSj/

You might need to play with the panel sizes in the fiddle to convince yourself that it works.

Answer (score 3):

either set width to 100% on tables or put a width on their parent element with width 285px

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, pure `floating` wont do what you want it to in this case. The simplest fix is non-semantic: Wrap the left column in a `div` that's `floated` to the `left`, with a width of 50% or some other suitable number, and wrap the right column in a `div` that's `floated` to the `right`, with a width of 50% or some other suitable number.

The alternative to preserve semantics unfortunately relies on either absolute positioning (which wont work for dynamic tables) or JavaScript. [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) is a reasonable way of aligning columns of stuff so that it all fits together nicely, but unfortunately will not work for users without JavaScript enabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
table {
    display: block;
    width: 285px;
}
```